# Page not found - Even after I implemented Hook_Menu()

Tags: 7, routes

I have implemented hook_menu() & called a function, but if I am trying to browse the page URL it's giving me "Page not found" error...

This is the code --

```
function user_type_registration_menu(){
  $items = array();
    $items['paypal/payment/ipn'] = array(
          'title' => t('Paypal Payment IPN'),
          'description' => t('Paypal Payment IPN'),
          'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
          'page callback' => 'paypal_payment_paypal_ipn_callback',
          'access callback' => TRUE,
        );   
      return $items;
}
function paypal_payment_paypal_ipn_callback(){      
  dpm("here");
}
```

I have cleared the cahche too..so cahche can't be the problem...

Comment: have you created the callback function

Comment: Yes you can see the callback below...

Comment: have you tried returning something rather than just a dump of the variable. the menu call back should return something to be displayed.

Comment: I have succeed with checking the path in this way previously. I am not returning some thing here because I have to call this path from paypal return...and while doing that so...it's giving me same error...

Comment: Does it work if you set 'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM ?

Comment: As side note, title and description are not passed to `t()`.

Comment: Did you edit an enabled module, or did you edit the module, and then enabled/installed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code you posted you will get a blank page.

If you actually return something from your callback you will get a proper page, with no 404 error.
A menu callback has to actually return something.

For example, this works:

```
function user_type_registration_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['paypal/payment/ipn'] = array(
    'title' => t('Paypal Payment IPN'),
    'description' => t('Paypal Payment IPN'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page callback' => 'paypal_payment_paypal_ipn_callback',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );

  return $items;
}

function paypal_payment_paypal_ipn_callback() {
  dpm("here");
  return 'test';
}
```

Also, make sure your module is named "user_type_registration" or else your menu hook will not get picked up.

Comment: Do you actually have to create a module for this or can you use your theme name?

Comment: You have to do hook_menu() from a module.